# Subnetting into 6 CIDR/24 network and 2 CIDR/27 networks?

Tags: subnet, ip-routing, cidr

I am revising some questions for an exam and one of the questions was provide the ip numbers and a diagram for a company which has 3 branches. Paris/Berlin/Cairo (random locations I know) Now I belive I have figured out the answer but I would appreciate someone checking as my brain is fried and I think if this answer is wrong I won't be able to see that's its wrong.

You have 3 routers which means 6 networks All should be /24, the IP addresses should resemble 10.12."network number"."host number" ie 10.12.59.1, so that its a /24 that means the mask is going to be 255.255.255.0,  so my host ranges are, not including broadcast addresses

- 1-30
- 33-62
- 65-94
- 97-126
- 129-158
- 161-190
- 193-222
- 225-254

So I could use 6 of them for my 6 networks, 1 for each of the branches and 1 for the 3 networks joining the branches.

The Berlin branch network is extended with 2 additional VLANS. These networks should be sub-netted from 10.12.59.0 with a /27 structure. Now this is where I start to know I am weak in my knowledge. the mask for a CIDR/27 is 255.255.255.224 but I cant figure out how to implment a /27 numbering within a /24 network. Can anyone explain please?

Comment: You're the teacher and you need help with subnetting?

Comment: @spacemanspiff - if he has a doubt or hesitation, would you prefer a teacher not ask for someone to double check? After working with teachers, I've learned their dirty secret...they're not infallible. :-)

Answer (score 5):

This is done with [Variable Length Subnetting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958815.aspx).

To do VLSN we just look at all our networks and arrange them in size. First the big ones then the smaller ones. You already have your /24 networks so to correct your subnets:

if you have 10.12.0.0 and you need 6 /24 networks and 2 /27, then we need to first accommodate the /24 networks:

So we get:

```
 Subnet 1:
10.12.0.0 (networkaddress)
10.12.0.1 (first host)
10.12.0.254 (last host)
10.12.0.255 (broadcast address)
Subnet 2:
10.12.1.0 (networkaddress)
10.12.1.1 (first host)
10.12.1.254 (last host)
10.12.1.255 (broadcast address)
Subnet 3:
10.12.2.0 (networkaddress)
10.12.2.1 (first host)
10.12.2.254 (last host)
10.12.2.255 (broadcast address)
Subnet 4:
10.12.3.0 (networkaddress)
10.12.3.1 (first host)
10.12.3.254 (last host)
10.12.3.255 (broadcast address)
Subnet 5:
10.12.4.0 (networkaddress)
10.12.4.1 (first host)
10.12.4.254 (last host)
10.12.4.255 (broadcast address)
Subnet 6:
10.12.5.0 (networkaddress)
10.12.5.1 (first host)
10.12.5.254 (last host)
10.12.5.255 (broadcast address)
```

Now we need to accommodate two /27 networks in one more /24 networks. Let's first see if two /27  fit into a /24:

```
/27 = 32 IP's (1 network, 30 hosts, 1 broadcast). 
/24 = 256 IP's (1 network, 254 hosts, 1 broadcast).
```

So we can fit in 8 /27 networks basically, but we only need two, our network address to put the /27 in is 10.12.6.0. So now you start as you would do normally:

```
Subnet 7:
10.12.6.0 (networkaddress)
10.12.6.1 (first host)
10.12.6.30 (last host)
10.12.6.31 (broadcast address)
Subnet 8:
10.12.6.32 (network address)
10.12.6.33 (first host)
10.12.6.62 (last host)
10.12.6.63 (network address)
```

Good luck with your exam :)

Comment: Sorry Can you just explain how you can fit 4 x /27 networks into a /24 I get confused combining the 2 - Thanks

Comment: I did...it's basic math you have a /24 network (10.12.6.0/24) you just  look how many times a /27 can fit in there (8 times 8*32=256). So you just subnet within your /24, starting with the /24 first ip. I mean it's not different from subnetting a /24, because that can basically be a subnet within a /23.